# How to get Appstats data for a Cloud Endpoint method?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

With Appstats I get nice insights about the RPC performance of my application.

How can I make the endpoints requests visible in the Appstats Dashboard?

Comment: This is a feature we are working on. No ETA yet. If you are interested in being a trusted tester, please let me know.

Comment: Just to update, it works now, couldn't find the documentation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739458/setting-up-metrics-for-google-cloud-endpoints/32740332#32740332