# Setting up metrics for Google Cloud endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to set up Google Cloud endpoints on a production server. What would be a good way to profile requests? [Appstats](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats?hl=en) support only WSGI requests.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could actually solve this. Digging into endpoints, I could see that it is actually a WSGI server. And tested it with Appstats and works perfectly, it needs to be added to documentation.

In appengine_config.py, I did this:

```
def webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(app):
    from google.appengine.ext.appstats import recording
    app = recording.appstats_wsgi_middleware(app)
    return app
webapp_add_wsgi_middleware(api_app)
```

This works well on production too.

Comment: Correct. Cloud Endpoints is an API proxy that translates API requests and forwards them off to the protorpc backend `/_ah/spi/*` routes. Those routes are the ones you would profile. You will not see any `/_ah/api/*` requests in your log viewer.